# start other makefile within makefile

Tags: makefile

Since i am not so experienced with the building process / makefiles on linux i ran in follow problem:

the Setup:
i have an makefile A, which needs some enviroment variables set before running, this is done by running `. ./set_A_vars.sh` (set_A_vars.sh contains many `export` lines) before running `make -f A`

now i need to make project A within a makefile B.
i tried the following setup for makefile B:

```
all: debug release

A_debug:
    . ./set_A_vars.sh && make -f A DEBUG=1

A_release:
    . ./set_A_vars.sh && make -f A DEBUG=0

debug:   A_debug some_B_stuff_debug
release: A_release some_B_stuff_debug
```

however i get lots of errors, which sound like the enviroment variables in set_A_vars.sh have not been set for `make -f A ...` in B.

How can i call makefile A from makefile B with the enviroment variables in set_A_vars.sh set in makefile B ??

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your makefile looks good with these provisos:

1. When you call make from a makefile, please use the macro invocation `${MAKE}` rather than plain `make`. (This ensures parallel make works, and also means it still works even if your make has another name (`GNUmake` say).)
2. If your targets do not correspond to actual files, then mark them with `.PHONY` (see below).
3. Does `some_B_stuff_debug` require A to be built first? Then you must tell make this.

   ```
   some_B_stuff_debug: A_debug
   some_B_stuff_debug: A_release
   ```

   This is clearly wrong. One way is to enforce the ordering via the shell.

Try something like this:

```
.PHONY: debug
debug:
    . ./set_A_vars.sh && ${MAKE} -f A DEBUG=1
    ${MAKE} some_B_stuff_debug

.PHONY: release
release:
    . ./set_A_vars.sh && ${MAKE} -f A DEBUG=0
    ${MAKE} some_B_stuff_debug

.PHONY: some_B_stuff_debug
∶
```

Comment: +1: some good information here (especially `.PHONY`, but still i dont think that this solves the problem at hand..

Comment: Try `set -x; . ./set_A_vars.sh && ${MAKE} -f A DEBUG=1`. This will cause `sh` to echo the lines of `set_A_vars.sh` as it executes them.

Comment: At the top of the makefile run by `${MAKE} -f A DEBUG=1`, try a few debug printfs. Things like: `$(message var MYVAR is [${MYVAR}] set from [$(origin MYVAR)])` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your makefiles should work. I suggest you try the following:

Try running `set_A_vars.sh` from the command line.

Verify that the variables you wanted set are set.

`make -f MakefileA`, to verify that `MakefileA` really does work nicely with these variables set.

Try a rule in `MakefileB` that will test one of the variables, say `FOO`:

```
test_var:
    @echo FOO is $(FOO)
```

This should work if you have just run `set_vars.sh`. If it doesn't, then there are a couple of things that could be wrong...

Now clear the variables (including `FOO`) and try this rule in `MakefileB`:

```
set_vars_and_test_them:
    ./set_A_vars.sh && echo FOO is $(FOO)
```

Now put it together:

```
A_debug:
    ./set_A_vars.sh && make -f MakefileA DEBUG=1
```

(I recommend against calling a makefile "A".)

Comment: you missread my Q, its `. ./set_A_vars` not `./set_A_vars.sh`, and before you ask, i am not the author of makefile A and set_A_vars.sh ..

Comment: @smerlin: I did not misread your question. I noticed the extra dot, which I assumed was simply bad design since it does nothing (because of the space). And I refer to makefile A as `MakefileA` for clarity.

Comment: MakefileA works nicely when done form a shell, and afaik the extra dot does something ... it shoud do the same as the csh `source` command.

Comment: I stand corrected; I'd never heard of the `.` convention before.

Comment: @Beta: `@echo FOO is $(FOO)` is incorrect. Make will expand `$(FOO)` _before_ running the shell. Presumably the expansion will be empty. You should use `echo "FOO is [$$FOO]"`. The square brackets help to emphasize empty expansions.

Comment: @bobbogo: `@echo FOO is $(FOO)` is correct, but `./set_A_vars.sh && echo FOO is $(FOO)
` is not. Thanks for the correction.